# Making soap api call from ssjs to create salesforce account record

Tags: api, soap, ssjs

I am trying to make a SOAP call to create new accounts and update campaign members in our sandbox salesforce crm from Marketing cloud landing page under webstudio

When I publish it, I am getting below error:

> {"StatusCode":500,"Response":"{\"message\":\"An error occurred when
>   attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call. See inner exception
>   for
>   details.\",\"description\":\"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException:
>   An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function
>   call. See inner exception for details.\r\n Error Code:
>   OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner
>   exception 1---\r\n\r\nSystem.Net.WebException: The remote server
>   returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. - from
>   System\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\"}"}

Please suggest.
Thanks!

Api call:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script language='javascript' runat=server>
    Platform.Load("core","1");
    var username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
var password = 'xxxxxxxxx';
var payload = '';
var endpoint = "https://tmca--uat.cs96.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/45.0";
var result;

payload += '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
payload += '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">';
payload += '   <soapenv:Header>';
payload += '         <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">';
payload += '            <UsernameToken>';
payload += '            <Username>username</Username>';
payload += '            <Password>password</Password>';
payload += '          </UsernameToken>';
payload += '      </Security>';
payload += '   </soapenv:Header>';
payload += '   <soapenv:Body>';
payload += '        <gues:guestWebservices>';
payload += '            <gues:request>';                     
payload += '                <gues:campaignDetailsWrapper>';
payload += '                <gues:campaignDetailList>';
payload += '                <gues:campaignCode>MOTO_86_2019PHIL</gues:campaignCode>';
payload += '                <gues:campaignName>Phillip Island 2019</gues:campaignName>';
payload += '                </gues:campaignDetailList>';
payload += '                </gues:campaignDetailsWrapper>';
payload += '                <gues:guestDetails>';
payload += '            <gues:email>rcoctober22@gmail.com</gues:email>';
payload += '            <gues:firstName>Rohit</gues:firstName>';
payload += '            <gues:lastName>Chauhan</gues:lastName>';
payload += '            <gues:phone>8700xxxxxx</gues:phone>';
payload += '            <gues:personmobilephone>8700668828</gues:personmobilephone>';
payload += '            </gues:guestDetails>';
payload += '            <gues:webFormType>Sponsorships_Events</gues:webFormType>';
payload += '            </gues:request>';
payload += '        </gues:guestWebservices>';
payload += '   </soapenv:Body>';
payload += '</soapenv:Envelope>';

  try {
    result = HTTP.Post(endpoint, "text/xml", payload, ["SOAPAction"], ["Create"]);
} catch(e) {
    result = {StatusCode:500,Response:Stringify(e)};    
}

if (result.StatusCode != 200) {
    //Bad response
    Write(Stringify(result));
} else {
    //Good response
    Write(Stringify(result));
}

    </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the SOAP call works outside of the page -- like with SOAP UI or Postman?

Comment: Yes, Adam. I tried the soap envelope in SOAP UI and it worked fine and send data in sfdc.

Comment: You're not using the username and password variables in your payload...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Salesforce CRM Partner API doesn't support the same [UsernameToken authentication that Marketing Cloud does](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/authenticate-soap-api.htm#authenticate-with-usernametoken).

You can't just put the username and password details in a SOAP header for the Partner API. Instead you need to use the [login](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) call to get a session ID and Server URL. Those details can then be used via the SOAP SessionHeader to make subsequent calls.